# Change terminal prompt Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash

I have cloned a git repository to a folder in my workspace: /home/jose/workspace/very-very-very-long-repository-name/

so when i browse to it in my terminal it looks like

```
jose@jose-Vostro-1500:~/workspace/very-very-very-long-repository-name$
```

Is there a way of changing/editing/abbreviating the terminal prompt so that it doesn't fill the terminal!??

e.g

```
~/abbreviated/prompt$
```

Thanks,
W

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The prompt is controlled by the `PS1` environment variable.

`echo $PS1` to see what you have now. It'll be a combination of actual characters like `@` and escape characters like `\u` for user and `\h` for hostname.

[This generator](http://www.kirsle.net/wizards/ps1.html) helps you make your own

[This script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5687446/bash-custom-ps1-with-nice-working-directory-path) gives a nice method of shortening the directory path.

Put this `PS1="whatever"` into the last line of your `~/.bashrc`, then either log out and log in, or `source ~/.bashrc` to apply.

There are also PS2, PS3 and PS4 variables that define various other behaviours. You can read about them on [thegeekstuff.com](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/09/bash-shell-take-control-of-ps1-ps2-ps3-ps4-and-prompt_command/).

Comment: Great, thanks for the tip... i just edited PS1 in .bashrc to be "$ "...

Answer (score 0):

In Bash 4 and later, you can use the special variable `PROMPT_DIRTRIM`. The escapes `\w` or `\W` are available in at least Bash 3.2 and later. These features can be used to control the length of the current directory as displayed in your prompt.

> PROMPT_DIRTRIM
>                 If  set  to a number greater than zero, the value is used as the number of trailing directory components to retain
>                 when expanding the \w and \W prompt string escapes (see PROMPTING below).  Characters removed are replaced with an
>                 ellipsis.
>
> \w
>   the  current  working  directory, with $HOME abbreviated with a tilde (uses the value of the PROMPT_DIRTRIM variable)
>
> \W
>   the basename of the current working directory, with $HOME abbreviated with a tilde

Answer (score 0):

To solve the problem of log folder names (or deep nested folders) remeber that in Bash you can put a new line (`\n`) into the `$PS1` prompt like this:

```
export PS1="[\u@\h \W]\n$ "
```

This will give you a two line prompt like this :

```
[user@host ~/workspace/very-very-very-long-repository-name$] 
$
```

The prompt will be on the second line after the `$`.